# How to get a fully transparent TabBar in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, transparent

I have spent the last few hours trying to get the TabBar in a UITabBarController fully transparent (clear background). I use a custom subclass of the UITabBarController and I managed to change the tintColor, the alpha, but the background color definitely remains the one defined in IB.
Thanks for your help, I'm getting crazy...

Comment: It doesn't work actually...

Comment: Just edited my answer with a different solution. See if that works for you.:)

Comment: as promised i just added the line of code you need to change the background color of your tab bar in latest iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to accomplish that.

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 48);//Setting a Frame.

myTabView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];//Making Tab View

// not supported on iOS4    
UITabBar *tabBarr = [self.tabBar tabBar];
if ([tabBarr respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:)])
{
    // set it just for this instance
    [tabBarr setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hot-1.png"]];


    // set for all
    // [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: ...
}
else
{
    // ios 4 code here
    //[tabBarr setBackgroundColor:c];
}

//[myTabView  setBackgroundColor:c];//Setting Color Of TaBar.

[myTabView  setAlpha:0.8];//Setting Alpha of TabView.

[[self.tabBar tabBar] insertSubview:myTabView  atIndex:0];//Inserting Tab As SubView.
```

And here is a link to a tutorial I found very useful in changing the tab bar's background. You can play around with the code and costomize it to your liking.

http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-customize-the-tab-bar-using-ios-5-appearance-api/

Edit:

As far as setting the background color of tabbar to transparent or clear color, you have two ways. One is the image which I explained and you didn't like. The other one is to set the background of tabbar in its supper view. Something along the following line.

```
tabBar.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This way you reach behind the tabbar and change that black background to whatever you want.

Edit 1:

sorry for delay in adding the solution for ios 7. below is the method you need to change the background color of the tabbar in ios 7.

just add the following line of code inside your `ViewDidLoad` method and it will do the magic.

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

hope this helps.:)

Comment: Thanks. This works if you want to have a background based on an image. I have tried [[UITabBar appearance] setColor: [UIColor clearColor]], with no success...

Comment: @jcr, check the edit section of my answer.

Comment: Hmm..After having spent a bit more time on the internet, It seems that things has changed a little bit in ios7 regarding the color of navBar, tabBar, etc... But I'm not sure that I can explain here what. Anyway, thank you for your answer which should work in ios6.

Comment: @jcr, I was unaware that you are looking for iOS 7 solution. I provided the answers related to the question and the tags. If you need the solution for ios7 let me know.

Comment: I didn't specify it as it is not really allowed to speak about ios7 at the moment... But if you have the solution, I would be more than happy ! :)

Comment: @jcr, I will. As soon as I get back home to my Mac. But I believe as far as the question is concerned my answer was correct. Wasn't it?